# Progress towards Outspoken badge

Tags: support, badges

In my mad rush to f̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶c̶k̶  burnish my credentials for the moderator election, I have noticed that I am missing one vital badge: Outspoken

[image: [outspoken]]

I am now aware that you can check your own starred posts:

[image: starred posts]

The condition, however, is that the posts are starred by different users
[image: starred posts by different users]

How are we to know?

Comment: I don't think you can; stars, like votes, aren't public information for "who", only "how many".  (But I don't know for sure, hence just leaving this comment.)

Comment: You have one more "different user" now :)

Answer (score 2):

This information *used to* be available (albeit through a bug, and hidden in the websocket's frames) through the websocket chat uses to communicate with the server.

That bug has now been fixed, and the information is no longer available. Same for flags, actually.